# How to properly check for list item and log if it has been checked?

Tags: python, list, random

Trying to make a crack the code console game similar to the game called " Mastermind " for a school project.  Example : http://www.webgamesonline.com/mastermind/
whitecheck should be:  correct number but wrong position.
redcheck should be: correct number and position.

however, if i run the code it will bug out and tell me there's 1 whitecheck and 1 redcheck depending on the position of the guessed number regardless of wether the answer has been given at the end.

player selects 4 numbers in a range of 1-4.
If player guesses the correct number but it's in the wrong position it should show a white dot to indicate that.
If player guesses the correct number AND position it should show a red dot to indicate that.

problem is that if i run the code like this it will check the first number first and if it's the right number but in the wrong position it will add it to the whitecheck list.

This shouldn't happen if the correct number and position has been given for that exact same number when it checks for another later in the code.

I've tried appending the guessed answers to an empty checklist but i need the program to check them all at once so it doesnt give me a whitecheck if there's a redcheck for the same number at the end.

```
   import random


code = []
attempts = 3

while len(code) != 4:
    for x in range(4):
        n = random.randint(1, 4)
        if n not in code:
            code.append(n)
print(code)

pos1 = str(code[0])
pos2 = str(code[1])
pos3 = str(code[2])
pos4 = str(code[3])

answer = str(pos1) + str(pos2) + str(pos3) + str(pos4)

guess = None

while guess != answer:

    positionguess1 = str(input("position 1: "))
    positionguess2 = str(input("position 2: "))
    positionguess3 = str(input("position 3: "))
    positionguess4 = str(input("position 4: "))
    checklist = []
    whitecheck = 0
    redcheck = 0

    """ Row 1 code check """
    if positionguess1 == pos1:
        redcheck += 1
        checklist.append(positionguess1)
    elif positionguess1 != pos1 and positionguess1 in answer and positionguess1 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess1)
        whitecheck += 1

    """ Row 2 code check """
    if positionguess2 == pos2:
        redcheck += 1
        checklist.append(positionguess2)
    elif positionguess2 != pos2 and positionguess2 in answer and positionguess2 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess2)
        whitecheck += 1

    """ Row 3 code check """
    if positionguess3 == pos3:
        redcheck += 1
        checklist.append(positionguess3)
    elif positionguess3 != pos3 and positionguess3 in answer and positionguess3 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess3)
        whitecheck += 1

    """ Row 4 code check """
    if positionguess4 == pos4:
        checklist.append(positionguess4)
        redcheck += 1
    elif positionguess4 != pos4 and positionguess4 in answer and positionguess4 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess4)
        whitecheck += 1

    crackattempt = str(positionguess1) + str(positionguess2) + str(positionguess3) + str(positionguess4)

    print ("You've entered:", crackattempt)

    if crackattempt == answer:
        print ("Amount in wrong position with right value:", whitecheck)
        print("Amount in the right position and the right value:", redcheck)
        print ("cracked the code, you win")
    elif attempts == 0:
        print ("you lose.")
        break
    elif crackattempt != answer:
        print ("Wrong! Try again.")
        print("Amount in wrong position with right value:", whitecheck)
        print("Amount in the right position and the right value:", redcheck)

        attempts -= 1
```

If the randomly generated code is e.g. ' 1234 '  and the guessed code is ' 4234, it should give me 3 redcheck instead of 3 redcheck + 1 whitecheck

I THINK i solved it by seperating the redcheck from the whitecheck statements.

```
    """ correct number and correct position check """
    if positionguess1 == pos1:
        redcheck += 1
        checklist.append(positionguess1)


    if positionguess2 == pos2:
        redcheck += 1
        checklist.append(positionguess2)


    if positionguess3 == pos3:
        redcheck += 1
        checklist.append(positionguess3)


    if positionguess4 == pos4:
        checklist.append(positionguess4)
        redcheck += 1

    """ correct number but wrong position checks """

    if positionguess1 != pos1 and positionguess1 in answer and positionguess1 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess1)
        whitecheck += 1

    if positionguess2 != pos2 and positionguess2 in answer and positionguess2 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess2)
        whitecheck += 1

    if positionguess3 != pos3 and positionguess3 in answer and positionguess3 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess3)
        whitecheck += 1

    if positionguess4 != pos4 and positionguess4 in answer and positionguess4 not in checklist:
        checklist.append(positionguess4)
        whitecheck += 1
```

Comment: this code could be much simpler...eg. ```code="1234"; guess="4234"; redcheck = sum([code[i]==guess[i] for i in range(0, 4)]); print(redcheck)```

Comment: bit lost on the whitecheck aspect and the game in general. Can you play out a fictional game and edit the question with this?

Comment: I suppose i could just edit the post so it holds the entire file as it's not that much larger.

Comment: Why the pygame tag? There is no use of the pygame library here.

Comment: Sorry about that valentino, i created the GUI for this game in pygame and tkinter and forgot that it's not used in this snippet. I'll try to edit the tag out.

Comment: Am i allowed to link a free to play game here to show you which game i'm trying to reproduce? it's my first time posting here.

Comment: Yes, is not a problem as long it is helpful to better understand the question. Or maybe you can just link the rule of the game

Comment: http://www.webgamesonline.com/mastermind/ this is basically what it needs to be. I'm trying to reproduce this game in console first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in the logic. Let's have a look at this snippet

```
""" Row 1 code check """
elif positionguess1 != pos1 and positionguess1 in answer and positionguess1 not in checklist:
    checklist.append(positionguess1)
    whitecheck += 1
```

Here the code checks if the number entered by the user in the first row is in another row. In case of repeated numbers like in your example (user inputs 4234, correct answer 1234) it finds that 4 is not in the first row but is present, so it adds the whitecheck.  `checklist` is used to exclude numbers already tested, but being the first row tested, checklist is empty, so will always add a whitecheck.

To fix this, instead of checking by row, you should first check for exact number and add all of them in the checklist, if present. Then, check for correct numbers in the wrong position.

Comment: I'm relieved that you understand my problem as i realise my explanation was quite bad but now i'm having problems with understanding how i can implement your suggested fix. Could you perhaps show me an example in code?

Comment: I'll have a look and edit my answer in a while, but since it's a school project, I will not give you a full working code: it's against the guidelines: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/10426037

Comment: I think i solved it by seperating the if and elif statements. It's not bugging out so far!
The program will now first do the redchecks and after that's done it will do the whitechecks and it works just fine.   I edited the main post, i'm hoping you could give me some feedback. 
```

Comment: Yes, that is one way.

Comment: With your edit seems to work as expected. If you're ok with that, I'll leave my answer as it is. In general, you can shorten the code in several points, but since it's your homework, better to leave it like that. This way it's really _your_ homework.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - per edits not same game but not deleted as there are useful ideas in the code for OP

Code below is implementation of what I believe is the game.

```
import random

code = random.randint(1000, 9999)

def checks(code, guess):
    """Return tuple with redchecks and whitechecks"""
    code = str(code)
    guess = str(guess)
    redcheck = sum([code[i]==guess[i] for i in range(0, 4)])
    whitecheck = sum([
      code[i]!=guess[i] and (code[i] in guess)
      for i in range(0, 4)
    ])
    return (redcheck, whitecheck)

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input('Guess:'))
    except:
        print('Exit game')
        break
    if code == guess:
        print('You win!!')
        break
    print(checks(code, guess))
```